# conjugacy of elements of group $GL_2(\mathbb{Z_p})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For a prime $p$, consider the group $GL_2(\mathbb{Z_p})$.Then every element of order $p$ is conjugate to a  matrix \begin{pmatrix}
1 &a \\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},where $a\in \mathbb{Z_p}$

My approach to solution-The given group  has order $(p^2-p)(p^2-1)$ ,hence By the Sylow's theorem it has 1 or $p+1$  numbers of Sylow's -$p$ subgroups of order $p$ ,which is  a cyclic subgroup.Now we know from Sylow's 2nd theorem every sylow -$p$ subgroups are conjugate to each other.The given matrix also has a order $p$

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &a \\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^p=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ so this matrix will belong to some sylow -$p$ subgroup,thus every element of order $p$ is conjugate to this matrix.

does my approach to this question is right? (THIS QUESTION IS ALREADY ASKED BUT I AM CURIOUS ABOUT MY APPROACH)

Thnakyou.

Comment: Could I assume that your $\mathbb{Z}_{\mathbb{p}}$ is a finite field with $p$ elements, not a $p$-adic integer?

Comment: finite field with p elements

Answer (score 2):

An element of order $p$ is contained in a Sylow subgroup so it will be conjugate to an element from a fixed Sylow subgroup, in this case the subgroup of upper triangular matrices with $1$ on the diagonal. Worth noting so all the elements  $\ne I$ from that subgroup are conjugate.